# Udp not receiving data from server (android client, pc java server)

Tags: android, server, udp, client

i am making a chat application for android using UDP.

Everything works fine in lan devices, I can send and receive messages from client and from server.

When i connect to an other network with my android, i can send messages, the server receives them but the response is never received on android.

Client Receive code

```
 Runnable periodicTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Invoke method(s) to do the work
        System.out.println("Waiting for data");
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[2028];
        byte[] sendData = new byte[2028];

        boolean portTaken=false;
        DatagramSocket serverSocket=null;
        ServerSocket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new ServerSocket(6667);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERRORRRRRRRRRRRRRR");
        } finally {
            if (socket != null)
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    serverSocket= new DatagramSocket(6667);
                } catch (IOException e) {   e.printStackTrace();   }
        }

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new     DatagramPacket(receiveData,receiveData.length);

        try {
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            System.out.println("GOT THEM!");
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(receiveData);

        ObjectInputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Data student = null;
        try {
            student = (Data) is.readObject();
            l.add(student.toString());

            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            System.out.println(student);
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

};
```

Server Send Code

```
for (DatagramPacket packet:clients){
            if (!packet.getAddress().equals(receivePacket.getAddress())){
                System.out.println("current ip address " + receivePacket.getAddress());
                System.out.println("Sending to " + packet.getAddress());
                DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
                InetAddress local =packet.getAddress();//editTextAddress.getText().toString());//InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.74");
                System.out.println(local.toString());
                //int msg_length =student.//sentence.length();



                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);

                os.writeObject(student);

                byte[] data2 = outputStream.toByteArray();
                int msg_length =data2.length;
                DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(data2, msg_length, local,
                        6667);
                s.send(p);
                s.close();

            }
```

What might be the case ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: You don't need to create a new socket every time you want to send something. You can use use the same socket you are listening on,

Comment: i changed that, but still i dont receive any message on my device